# Как можно быстро в обычном текстовом файле удалить все строки содержащие заданное слово?

Tags: редактор-текста, shell, sql, text, текст

Есть файл с SQL командами, чтобы его исполнить надо предварительно удалить все лишнее. Формат примерно такой:

```
UPDATE ...
UPDATE ...
UPDATE ...
...
20121211 done.
...
20121212 done.
```

Подойдет любой быстрый способ удалить все строки содержащие слово done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямо в редакторе GUI СУБД (например, SS Management Studio)заменить done на пустую строку по всему тексту.

Кажется, я не правильно понял вопрос. Если нужно удалить всю строку, в которой есть слово done, то в предположении, что число - это дата, и год/месяц не меняются, то в Word'е можно использовать такую замену:

Найти: 201212^#^#^wdone.

Заменить на: <оставить пустым>

Answer (score 3):

Если не строго слово, а символы `done`, то

```
cp myfile myfile.bak; grep -v done myfile.bak > myfile
```

Comment: @avp: А чтобы было слово надо просто `\b` (или `\<` с `\>`) добавить, не забыв включить `-E`.

Comment: @drdaeman, это отлично (совершенно правильно), но может оказаться не совсем быстро. Надо подумать, может быть что-то про регулярные выражения вспомнить или прочитать (освежить).

А так, если конечно для конкретных данных подходит (а я надеюсь TC  их видит) 30 секунд (с запасом).

Если просто **done** не годится, то можно **' done\\.'** попробовать.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял, у вас этот файл генерируется другим SQL запросом. чтобы не выводилось (... done), впишите в начале генерирующего запроса

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Совет актуален для MS SQL.

Comment: MS SQL обычно пишет что-то вроде (NN row(s) affected)

Answer (score -1):

1. Пуск выполнить -> notepad
2. Жмем CTRL+H
3. Заменить что done
      Заменить чем (пустоту оставляем)
4. Жмем ОК

---

Извиняюсь. Не получится так... Нужно ставить NotePad++, и заменять с использованием регулярного выражения.